# Inno Installer Doesn't Uninstall any files

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

So, I just picked up Inno today, to try and get a basic installer for a Unity game. The installer portion of Inno works perfectly, unfortunately, the uninstaller doesn't work at all. I've gone through the docs, and trawled Google, and haven't seen much on this exact problem. The Inno docs recommend using the [UninstallDelete] section, which I've tried, with similar results.

```
[Setup]
AppName=Installable Files
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Installable Files
DefaultGroupName=Installable Files                              
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\File.exe
Compression=lzma2
UninstallFilesDir={app}\uninst
SolidCompression=yes

[Files]
Source: "File.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "File.exe"
Source: "Files\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Files"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "Files\README.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Files"; Filename: "{app}\File.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{pf}\Files"
```

The output from the above code says it's deleting all the files in the subdirs, but fails to delete the directory w/ (145) error code, and then states the unistallation process succeeded. This is the same whether I run the uninstaller from the Inno Setup Compiler, the uninst000.exe, or from the Add/Remove Programs in Windows.

An installer/uninstaller that doesn't actually uninstall anything is annoying, so if there's any insight into this problem that'd be great.

(Please note I've also tried deleting individual files under [UninstallDelete] such as `Type: files; Name: "{app}\LGODemo.exe"` with zero success)

EDIT:
[After Install](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68904454/AfterInstall.png)

[After Uninstall](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/68904454/AfterUninstall.png)

As the images show, none of the files get deleted, due to a 145 error. The uninstaller then tries again, and apparently deletes the folders, except they still exist, and the file is still 100% executable. I only added the UninstallDelete section when the inital uninstall file failed.

Sorry for the dropbox links, can't post imgs until I have a better rep.

Comment: Hmm, I never use `[UninstallDelete]` section in my InnoSetup script and still the InnoSetup uninstaller works correctly. I wonder what is wrong in your InnoSetup script...

Comment: Maybe, you should put double-quotes in between those strings with spaces under `[Setup]` section...just my guess for a solution...

Comment: Or, you can define a variable to represent a repetitive string: for example `#define MyTitleName "Life Goes On Demo"` and use the `{#MyTitleName}` identifier like this: `DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyTitleName}`. By doing this, you can avoid the mistake due to unseen whitespaces in those repetitive strings.

Comment: Thanks for you responses, I tried both of them, with no luck. The uninstaller doesn't seem to have any difficulty locating the path/files to delete, it just fails to actually delete them. Almost makes me think it's a permissions issue, but wouldn't it throw an error if that was the case?

Comment: Which files/directories that aren't deleted? Can you snapshot a few images before and after un-installation and attach them in your post?

Comment: I suspect something is still accessing the `{app}\LGODemo_Data` folder, blocking InnoSetup from properly deleting that folder. Try to investigate what is locking the folder using SystemInternals' Process Explorer.

Comment: Ok, I have checked the error code 145; it says  The directory is not empty (ERROR_DIR_NOT_EMPTY). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx OK, I think you need to change the strategy by copying all required folders and files under a special folder called `install` and copy everything from this folder into the InnoSetup distribution file as follows: `Source: "install\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;`

Comment: It seems that those files are locked still, cauing Inno to have to leave them.

Comment: Ok, I hate magic problems. I tried it today after leaving it for a week, and suddenly the uninstall works perfectly. I've removed the UninstallDelete section, due to the reasons mentioned in the doc and by Deanna. If I figure out exactly why this started working I'll post again. Thanks for pointing me towards Process Explorer @eee

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've told it otherwise, Inno will remove everything that it installed.

Also, doing an explicit `[UninstallDelete]` on a folder can have adverse side effects, especially if you have the wrong path (`{app}` vs `{pf}\blah`). Imagine if someone installed your app into `C:\Windows\`? You've just wiped out their Windows installation!

Comment: Thanks, and I did read this in the docs, however, my issue is that Inno isn't deleting any files regardless, which it should, unless, as you've mentioned, I've told it not to, which I'm pretty sure I haven't. Had the UninstallDelete worked in my testing, I would have specified the folders/files specifically. Thanks for the response  though.

Comment: "Imagine if someone installed your app into C:\Windows\? You've just wiped out their Windows installation!" no you wiped their C:\Windows\blah folder, also this is not an answer to the question at all

Comment: @Soraphis only if they installed into `c:/windows/blah/`. Inno can be told not to force a subfolder.

Comment: @Soraphis my example also explicitly says `{app}` which may not have the suffix.

Comment: @Deanna yeah thats correct ... but its still not a solution to the question.

Comment: @Soraphis no, the answer was in the first sentence.

Comment: @Deanna obviously it didn't work for OP, and it does not work for me. `[UninstallDelete]` does not have any effect. Which your statement "it will remove everything that it installed" does not solve at all. if this statement would've been a useful answer this question might have an accepted answer at all.

Answer (score -2):

I got what you are doing wrong, you should remove the

`UninstallFilesDir={app}\uninst` part Default is `{app}`

And dont use `[UninstallDelete]`.with the above method it should remove all the files.
If you want to use `[UninstallDelete]` then use

[UninstallDelete]
    Name: {app}\; Type: filesandordirs

Instead of

`[UninstallDelete]
  Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{pf}\Files"`

**TRY IT**

Comment: No. Do not try it. There was no problem here. You are supposed to use `[UninstallDelete]` section only for files that were not installed by the installer (which was not the case here). And path to the uninstaller does not change anything. Besides, you would not need to specify `UninstallFilesDir={app}` value as `{app}` is the default value.

Comment: @TLama I know that default value is `{app}` .I use  `UninstallFilesDir={app}` because he use `UninstallFilesDir={app}\uninst`. I was just giving him the idea.